# How to check an image size (W x H), before uploading?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using JavaScript code to upload an image in FireBase/FireStore.

The core functionality already works, I can upload, but I also need to check the size of the image before uploading. And this is where I would be glad to get some help.

The following is my significant code. And the part between the lines:

```
// Trying to get the size:
```

and:

```
// End of trial code.
```

is not working.

```
upLdBtn.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // Get the file.
    var artWorkFile = e.target.files[0];

    // Trying to get the size:
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        window.alert('Size = ' + this.width + 'x' + this.height);
    }
    img.src = artWorkFile;
    // End of trial code.

    DoSomthingUseful(artWorkFile);
});
```

Comment: Are you really uploading an image to Firestore? Or are you actually using Cloud Storage? Firestore is probably not your best bet for images.

Comment: Try to load the image from a browser tab directly using the URL. Did you open the developer tools / console to check if there is any error?

Comment: @DougStevenson I think OP meant Firestore because it is basically impossible to upload an image to Firestore.

Comment: @DarrowHartman You mean the OP meant Cloud Storage, not Firestore (and it's not at all impossible to write an image to a Firestore document - just use a binary field under 1MB).

Comment: I am using Firebase Storage and the uploading part is working perfectly. I just would like to perform some checking on the image size before executing the upload.

Answer (score 3):

First,we need to set upload img from `input` to a `img` container src,after from this `img` element, we might get the original value of the image's width and height.

Here is the code snippet:

```js
function setSrc(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      $('#proImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}

$("#imgInp").change(function () {
  setSrc(this);
  setTimeout(getImgRatio,300);
});
function getImgRatio(){
 var imgStyleProp = getComputedStyle(proImg);
      var w =imgStyleProp.width;
      var h =imgStyleProp.height;
      console.log(w+"/"+h);
}
```

```css
img{
 width:initial;
 height:initial;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="file" id="imgInp" required="required" class="custom-file-input">
<img id="proImg" src=""/>
```

Comment: Following the idea that I can get in this snippet. I can fire a message with this kind of code:
"var reader = new FileReader(); reader.onload = function (e) {window.alert('Some-Message');}; reader.readAsDataURL(artWorkFile);"
But I would like the message to display (width,height).

Comment: If you think this is your answer,please mark it as answer.

Comment: That is the point, it has clearly put me on a good track and this is why I voted it up, but I cannot say this was the solution.

Comment: I actually gave my final code as an answer. Please have a look if you want.

Answer (score 0):

..........

Here is the finally working code:

```
upLdBtn.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    // Get the file.
    var upLoadFile = e.target.files[0],
    reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = (function(elt) { 
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = elt.target.result;

        image.onload = function() {
            if ((this.width != 100) || (this.height != 100)) {
                window.alert('Only 100x100 is allowed !!');
                return;
            }

            // Useful-Code-To-Perform-theUpLoad ....
            ..............
        };
    });

    reader.readAsDataURL(upLoadFile);
});
```

This solution has found a very important help in the answer by Md. Amirozzaman.

Answer (score -1):

You need to add `this.style.height` and `this.style.width` to access this property in CSS.